# 'which' command return two outputs

Tags: bash, shell, vim

I have a MacBook Pro 13, with OSX 10.12.6 with vim7.4 already installed.

I reinstalled vim with `$ brew install vim` to get vim8.1. The installation succeeded but when I call by with `$ vim` the one that opens is the 7.4 version, not the new one.

I checked with `$ which vim` and the output is:

```
$ which vim
vim is /usr/bin/vim
vim is /usr/local/bin/vim
```

The last one is the one I need. How do I remove the first one? Is it preferable to point the first link to the second one instead of removing?

Comment: If you need the second result to be the one that runs when you type `vim`, then you need to make sure `/usr/local/bin/` appears before `/usr/bin/` in your `PATH` environment variable. As an alternative, you can add `alias vim=/usr/local/bin/vim` to your `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

As @MikeHolt pointed out:

In the PATH environment variable `/usr/local/bin/` should appear before `/usr/bin/`.
I added `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to my ~/.bash_profile and worked.